# LEFT JOIN query MYSQL does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables rtz_order and rtz_restaurant

From order I want purchaseprice from restaurant i want "restaurant_commission" both have a column called restaurant_id So i want to join these to tables and add the restaurant_commission tot the query. I have come up with this (the date part etc works, i was already using that but the query does not work since I added the join)

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
    order.orderpurchase,
    order.orderdate,
    order.status,
    order.restaurant_id,
    res.restaurant_commission,
    res.restaurant_id
FROM rt_order order 
    LEFT JOIN rt_restaurant res ON order.restaurant_id = res.restaurant_id
WHERE date(order.orderdate) >= date(?) AND date(order.orderdate) <= date(?) 
    AND order.restaurant_id = ? AND order.status = "completed"';
```

I have tried diffrent things but i do not see why this is going wrong

Comment: What's going wrong? Can you supply some sample data, the result you'd expect and the result you're actually getting?

Comment: @Zefnus If you're going to spam a million tag edits into the system, please take the time to fix *all* the problems with the questions

Comment: @meagar improve or too minor, your turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword.

Use backtics like:

```
`ORDER`
```

Check the complete list of reserved keywords [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

> NOTE : It is better to avoid reserved keywords for column names, but if you use then wrap them with backtics.

Comment: ahh,, yes... changed it to just "o" ..it works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your alias `order` is a [**MySQL reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Make it either `` `order` `` using backticks, or change the alias' name.